# strange Ruby behavior, same routine, different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone please explain why this would be happening?

In the first case, I am making the following call to a ROR text-field

```
<%= f.text_field :cust_street_address_2, :maxlength => '20', placeholder:
(@cart.errors[:cust_street_address_2].first || 'Apt 302 (not required)'),
:class => ('form-control' + (@carterror unless @cart.errors.keys.exclude? 
:cust_street_address_2).to_s) %>
```

and the result of the class is 'form-control form-errors' when I am expecting  just 'form-control' (I just left the field blank in the form and submitted but this field is allowed to be nil)

In the second case, I am using irb to try and replicate the issue to debut by making a new cart object and trying to save executing this line;

```
('form-control' + (@carterror unless @cart.errors.keys.exclude? :cust_street_address_2).to_s)
```

The result is correct 'form-control'

Explain the difference?

Comment: so the output of both examples are different in the same file?

Comment: how about writing your code like this instead: `"form-control #{@carterror unless @cart.errors.keys.exclude? 
:cust_street_address_2).to_s}"`.

Comment: No sorry that code is not valid.

Comment: I missed an opening `(`. `:class => "form-control #{(@carterror unless @cart.errors.keys.exclude? :cust_street_address_2).to_s}"`. But I guess it's an other issue you're having

Comment: You could simplify this a lot by using an array for the `class` attribute and doing `if foo.key?(:bar)` instead of `unless foo.keys.exclude?(:bar)`. Like so: `class: [ "form-control", @carterror if @cart.errors.key?(:cust_street_address_2) ]`.

Comment: :class => ['form-control', (@carterror if @cart.errors.key?(:cust_street_address_2))] with the parenthesis works.